# How can I keep an expression on a object's parameter so I can re-evaluate it

Tags: javascript, expression

Question is simple. Let's say I define an array and two global variables. Pseudocode:

```
var X;
var Y;
var pool=[];
```

And over the time this array is filled with objects randomly.

```
pool.push(Object1={a:X+Y,b:X*Y,c:X-Y,...});
pool.push(Object2={a:X/Y,b:X+2*Y,c:X-Y,...});
pool.push(ObjectN={a:X+8*Y,b:X*Y,c:X-Y,...});
```

The problem is I need to reevaluate each object's a,b,c parameters periodically, because X and Y have changed.

```
for(var i=0;i<pool.length;i++){
   reevaluate(pool[i]);
}
```

Is there any way to reevaluate the a,b,c... parameters without need to redefine them and being each object different? In other words, is there a way to keep the original expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an array of functions:

```
pool.push(function() { return {a:X+Y,b:X*Y,c:X-Y,...}; });
```

You can then call the functions whenever you want to get the current result.

You may want to maintain two arrays; one for the functions and one for the current cached values.

Comment: Thanks. This could be an option. How about storing the expression as a string and using eval()?

Comment: @Hismail: That is a bad idea; it's slow and prone to security holes.